# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

This exception is thrown in the lins `myList = results['users'];`. I also tried `myList = results['users'] as List<String>;`. The type of `results['users']` is `List<dynamic>`. Actually it contains Strings so why can't it be converted?

```
List<String> myList = List<String>();
results = await ApiService.searchUser();
setState(() {
  myList = results['users'];
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can build a new list

```
myList = new List<String>.from(results['users']);
```

or alternatively, use a cast:

```
myList = results['users'].cast<String>();
```

Note that `myList.runtimeType` will differ:

- `List<String>` in case of a new list
- `CastList<dynamic, String>` in case of a cast

See discussion on [Effective Dart: When to use "as", ".retype", ".cast"](https://github.com/dart-lang/site-www/issues/736)

> I would suggest that you hardly ever use cast or retype.
>
> - retype wraps the list, forcing an as T check for every access, needed or not.
> - cast optionally wraps the list, avoiding the as T checks when not needed, but this comes at a cost of making the returned object polymorphic (the original type or the CastList), which interferes with the quality of the code that can be generated.
>
> If you are going to touch every element of the list, you might as well copy it with
>
> ```
>  new List<T>.from(original)
> ```
>
> So I would only use cast or retype if my access patterns are sparse or if I needed to update the original.

Note that the discussion above refers to `retype` method, which was removed from Dart 2, but other points are still valid.