# Flutter Firestore: Building my model from a snapshot

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm struggling to build my model from firestore map. It seems basic yet I can't figure it out.

Here's my code :

#### firestore_service.dart

```dart
{
  // ...
  final FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  await _db
      .collection('Users')
      .doc('jWtp19r7g2b4wwMJ5yBi')
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) {
    print(snapshot);
    print(snapshot.runtimeType);

    final _data = snapshot.data() ?? {};
    print(_data);
    print(_data['uid']);

    final user = UserModel.fromJson(_data);
    print(user.uid);
    return user;
  });
}
```

#### user_model.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UserModel {
  // ...
  factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return UserModel(
      uid: json['uid'],
      username: json['username'],
      characterID: json['character_id'],
    );
  }
}
```

#### Terminal

[image: Error]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try this: `final _data = snapshot.data.data() ?? {};`

Comment: Thanks for answering @Mahmoud_Mehri. Doesn't seem to work... Here's the error `The method 'data' isn't defined for the class
'Map<String, dynamic>? Function()'`. This is weird because it confirms that it is a `Map<String, dynamic>`, yet it still crashes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so, I don't know if it's a "clean" way of doing it but I figured I could add another factory in my model to build specifically from Firestore.

Since the specific error was `Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'`, I duckduckgo-ed the error and found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60840265/12525881) :

#### service.dart

```dart
    await _db
        .collection('Users')
        .doc('jWtp19r7g2b4wwMJ5yBi')
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) {
      final _data = Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapshot.data() ?? {});
      print(_data.runtimeType);
      final user = UserModel.fromFirestore(_data);
      print(user.uid);
    });
```

#### user_model.dart

```dart
class UserModel {
  UserModel({
    required this.uid,
    required this.characterID,
    this.username,
  });

  final String uid;
  final String? username;
  final List<String> characterID;

  factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return UserModel(
      uid: json['uid'],
      username: json['username'],
      characterID: json['character_id'],
    );
  }

  factory UserModel.fromFirestore(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) {
    return UserModel(
      uid: json['uid'],
      username: json['username'],
      characterID: List<String>.from(json['character_id']),
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "uid": uid,
        "username": username,
        "character_id": characterID,
      };
}
```

I feel like it's not my factory's role to "filter / cast" the data but that's the only way I found it working.